# What is the "customModule" parameter in storyboard file?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

Recently I've added some targets to my project. Looking at the diff of my storyboard file I've noticed that `customModule="Target1Name"`. Looks like I can set it in IB where all my targets are listed. But this storyboard is universal for all the targets, so I didn't select anything.

[image]

I'd like to understand what is the `customModule` parameter and why it appears to be set to my Target1Name?

I've looked at some related posts, but couldn't understand of what the customModule is used for.

- [Unknown class in IB file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file)
- [IB file error at runetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725881/unknown-class-myclass-in-interface-builder-file-error-at-runtime)
- [Missed customModule="AppName"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655880/xcode-6-unknown-class-viewcontroller-in-interface-builder-file)

Comment: [Relevant documentation on Swift modules](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID4). Most of the time you just want to use the target's module, but sometimes you need to specify a custom module, such as when you're using third party libraries.